# Debugging an AutoCAD module

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, autocad

I am working on a project which is a dll module for AutoCAD, which adds some new functionality (like menus, objects, etc.) to the environment. Naturally, there are some bugs in the menus, objects of the module.

The problem is as follows, when I see some bug in a dialog, menu item, edit field, or during some operation how do I find the corresponding place in the source code that is responsible for it? What tools should I use besides the ordinary debugging?

I use C++ in VS2010. The source code has about 500 000 lines, so it takes some time to get acquainted with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the method I use for C#/.NET. I can't guarantee it will also work for C++ dlls but it's worth a try.

First, in the Visual Studio config file for your solution, add the following lines to the Debug|Any CPU configuration:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <!-- there should be other options already in here! -->
  <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
  <StartProgram>c:\program files\autocad2008\acad.exe</StartProgram>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I use AutoCAD 2008 - substitute the path to your executable. In Visual Studio you should be able to set this from the configuration screen but in the Express editions you need to make this change manually in notepad or a similar editor.

Next, make sure that any AutoCAD provided dll that you reference in your project has the Copy Local attribute set to `False`.

Set any breakpoints you want in your code.

Now when you 'run' the dll it should start AutoCAD.

Load your dll in AutoCAD using `netload` (Make sure you select a debug version - release versions won't work!)

The module should run to your first breakpoint.

Answer (score 4):

Autocad doesn't provide debug info for it's binaries (`pdb` files).

If the crash is in your module, it should be fairly easy to debug, just make sure you have the corresponding `pdb`'s and `dll`'s. By `dll`'s I'm also talking about `arx` and `dbx` files.

If the crash is in an AutoCAD module... well, from experience, I'm 99.9% sure that the source is your code, and not AutoCAD's.

Comment: Is your experience with AutoCAD? My estimate would be around the 98% chance. They quite often don't check for null in their parameters so make sure you do check that none of your arguments are null. Ditto with arguments out of range. You need to be very careful what you send to AutoCAD unmanaged functions, they can be quite fragile. There isn't a lot of try...catch in there.

Comment: @CADbloke indeed my experience :). I agree that it can be easily crashed, but if it does, it's most probably your fault - not opening an entity for write, re-opening an opened entity, etc...

Comment: Agree. It doesn't tolerate sloppy behaviour at all.